# Expired tokens are not deleted after expiration in django-rest-knox 4.1.0

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, token, django-rest-knox

I am using django-rest-knox 4.1.0 . In its documentation it says that expired tokens are deleted automatically. But it is not deleting the tokens.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
"DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
    "knox.auth.TokenAuthentication",
),
}

REST_KNOX = {
"SECURE_HASH_ALGORITHM": "cryptography.hazmat.primitives.hashes.SHA512",
"AUTH_TOKEN_CHARACTER_LENGTH": 321,
"TOKEN_TTL": timedelta(minutes=10),
}
```

In settings.py I gave 10 minutes for expiration of token (for testing purposes). ["TOKEN_TTL": timedelta(minutes=10)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOrZn.png)

I check the database after that time, they are not deleted. [pgadmin knox token table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aSOD.png) Also I try to send request with those expired tokens, the respond is successful.